# Splicing 6AWG Copper in a Subpanel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I’m wiring a critical loads subpanel, a Siemens 4 position, 2 phase small panel. I am powering this from a single phase Victron Multiplus-II which just outputs one hot leg, and want to use all 4 breaker spaces (no 2 phase breakers, all circuits in this sunpanel will be single phase, on the same phase) instead of being limited to two on a single phase. To do that I need to split my single phase 6AWG copper hot leg to both of the phase lugs in the subpanel. I’m a bit unsure how to do this split, ie via 3 #6’s under a huge wire nut, or with 2 crimped #6’s under one of the lugs as a jumper, or some other option Im not thinking of.

How would you do it?

Comment: I always use a main lug panel and then a breaker to tie the two hots together. But that requires two spaces.

Comment: Interesting @Ruskes, guess I could get a bigger panel and tie up two of the spots as the bridge. So something like a 50 amp breaker with a single piece of 6awg wire jumping the two legs? I would really like to keep this panel due to its size, any other way to tie 3 #6’s together maybe in an insulated terminal block or something like that?

Comment: Choosing tiny panels often comes back to bite you later, but that may be a lesson you have to learn for yourself.

Comment: What size is the breaker feeding this panel?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little .... .you have utility and inverter coming into a 4-position panel, so do you have only 2 positions remaining for loads?  If so why have a panel at all, you could use a boiler switch, no?  And why use #6 for this, do you have one huge critical load?

Comment: The utility power is a 20 amp circuit which feeds the victron directly so it doesn’t touch this panel. The victron can pass thru the 20a to this panel, but it can add another 25a simultaneously for 45a total. The victron would cut out past 45a and acts as a Circuit breaker. I’m thinking the insulated mac block is perfect for this application unless i swap out the panel for a bigger one

Answer (score 2):

Use a 3-hole (3-port) splice connector rated for 6AWG. Example below

*In the unlikely event that the lugs are listed/rated for use with two wires, you could just run a jumper, but that's unlikely.*

Technically you could also use a split-bolt connector listed/rated for 3 6AWG wires and a lot of self-fusing tape to insulate it, but that's **likely a poor choice** for the average DIY practitioner.